# What is the easiest way to demo a Tkinter project?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making my portfolio, I have two Tkinter projects and and Html/CSS/Javascript project on my portfolio .My Html/CSS/Javascript has a link on my portfolio it is a button labeled "demo" if you click it, it takes you to a domain/link you can use my project and test it out. I wanna do the same thing with my two Tkinter projects, so someone can easily use/play/test my project. What would be the best way to do this? Could I do this with flask? or could I have a download button to download Tkinter application so someone else can use it. Or What would be the easiest way to have someone else be able to use my Tkinter application.

Comment: tkinter is for desktop programs - so you can't use flask for it. You may only create download button. But it may need also to create .exe file (with ie. PyInstaller)  because people may not have Python installed. But on page you could also add screenshots or video - it is nice to see program before you download it.

Comment: eventually you may try to use portals like [replit.com](https://replit.com/) which run code on server and stream output to browser.

Comment: If you have your own server, you can try [`CloudTk`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/CloudTk).